# How to horizontal Auto Scrolling carousel (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i've got a carousel and it's moving horizontally by clicking on a button, but I need it to keep scrolling, as i'm new on jquery and javascript (also I ask you guys to be patient haha) 
I get a little confused with the codes.

Code:

```
/**
 * Custom button state handler for enabling/disabling button state. 
 * Called when the carousel has determined that the previous button
 * state should be changed.
 * Specified to the carousel as the configuration
 * parameter: prevButtonStateHandler
 **/
var handlePrevButtonState = function(type, args) {
    var enabling = args[0];
    var leftImage = args[1];
    if(enabling) {
        leftImage.src = "imagens/esq_ativo.jpg";    
    } else {
        leftImage.src = "imagens/esq_inativo.jpg";  
    }
};
/**
 * Custom button state handler for enabling/disabling button state. 
 * Called when the carousel has determined that the next button
 * state should be changed.
 * Specified to the carousel as the configuration
 * parameter: nextButtonStateHandler
 **/
var handleNextButtonState = function(type, args) {
    var enabling = args[0];
    var rightImage = args[1];
    if(enabling) {
        rightImage.src = "imagens/dir_ativo.jpg";
    } else {
        rightImage.src = "imagens/dir_inativo.jpg";
    }
};
/**
 * You must create the carousel after the page is loaded since it is
 * dependent on an HTML element (in this case 'mycarousel'.) See the
 * HTML code below.
 **/
var carousel; // for ease of debugging; globals generally not a good idea
var pageLoad = function() 
{
    carousel = new YAHOO.extension.Carousel("mycarousel", 
        {
            numVisible:        9,
            animationSpeed:    0.15,
            scrollInc:         9,
            navMargin:         15,
            prevElement:     "prev-arrow",
            nextElement:     "next-arrow",
            size:              18,
            prevButtonStateHandler:   handlePrevButtonState,
            nextButtonStateHandler:   handleNextButtonState
        }
    );
};
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, 'load', pageLoad);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initiate the carousel you need to set `autoPlay` with the interval value.

**Example**

```
carousel = new YAHOO.extension.Carousel("mycarousel", 
    {
        numVisible:        9,
        animationSpeed:    0.15,
        scrollInc:         9,
        navMargin:         15,
        prevElement:     "prev-arrow",
        nextElement:     "next-arrow",
        size:              18,
        prevButtonStateHandler:   handlePrevButtonState,
        nextButtonStateHandler:   handleNextButtonState,
        autoPlay: 1000
    }
```

### Update

To get the carousel to loop you need to set `wrap` to true.

**Example**

```
carousel = new YAHOO.extension.Carousel("mycarousel", 
{
    // Your previous settings
    wrap: true
}
```

Comment: That solve one problem, now it's not looping (sorry for this, but i'm really newbie at jquery)

Comment: Got it! Thank you for helping a newbie hahaha! 
Gotta study more...